# Firebase function error - Object is possibly 'undefined'

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to deploy a simple function to Firebase.

When a new `write` is made in collection `todos` , I want a notification to be sent to a subscriber with token:

`evGBnI_klVQYSBIPMqJbx8:APA91bEV5xOEbPwF4vBJ7mHrOskCTpTRJx0cQrZ_uxa-QH8HLomXdSYixwRIvcA2AuBRh4B_2DDaY8hvj-TsFJG_Hb6LJt9sgbPrWkI-eo0Xtx2ZKttbIuja4NqajofmjgnubraIOb4_`

In order to achieve this, I followed a tutorial but while deploying, it is giving error

Below is the code of my `function`:

```
import * as functions from 'firebase-functions';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.newSubscriberNotification = functions.firestore
.document('todos')
.onCreate(async event=>{
    const data = event.data();
    const workdesc = data.workdesc;
    const subscriber = "evGBnI_klVQYSBIPMqJbx8:APA91bEV5xOEbPwF4vBJ7mHrOskCTpTRJx0cQrZ_uxa-QH8HLomXdSYixwRIvcA2AuBRh4B_2DDaY8hvj-TsFJG_Hb6LJt9sgbPrWkI-eo0Xtx2ZKttbIuja4NqajofmjgnubraIOb4_";

// notification content
const payload = {
    notification: {
        title: 'new write in collection todos',
        body: workdesc,
       //body: 'body',
        icon: 'https://img.icons8.com/material/4ac144/256/user-male.png'
    }
}

// send notification
return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(subscriber, payload)

});
```

**error :**

```
src/index.ts:11:11 - error TS6133: 'workdesc' is declared but its value is never read.

11     const workdesc = data.workdesc;
             ~~~~~~~~

src/index.ts:11:22 - error TS2532: Object is possibly 'undefined'.

11     const workdesc = data.workdesc;

Found 2 errors.

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
npm ERR! functions@ build: `tsc`
npm ERR! Exit status 2
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the functions@ build script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
```

### Edit 1

After the 2 changes as guided, when I am deploying the function, it is still giving `HTTP Error: 400`, screenshot attached

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The TypeScript error messages are telling you that you have two problems.

First, you're trying to access a property of an object that could be undefined, which would result in a crash.  `data` could be undefined, because that's part of the signature of the function.  In practice, for an onCreate function, it will never be defined, so you can override it like this with the `!` operator to tell TypeScript you are sure it will never be undefined:

```
    const data = event.data()!;
```

The other error is telling you that you simply declared a variable that was never used.  You declared `workdesc`, but never used it.  Just remove it - it's not necessary to your code.  If you need to use it, then do so.

Comment: i edited my question, in my payload i am using it, but still getting this error `src/index.ts:10:11 - error TS6133: 'workdesc' is declared but its value is never read.

10     const workdesc = data.workdesc;`

Comment: You are still not actually using the value of workdesc.  You are passing a literal sting with the value "${workdesc}".  Just use workdesc alone and don't put it in quotes.

Comment: `  body: workdesc,` i think this solved the error but now new error popped up saying `Functions deploy had errors with the following functions:
        newSubscriberNotification` , `Error: Functions did not deploy properly.`

Comment: Sorry for bothering you again, i have updated the question, attached screenshot of error after both the changes guided by you.

Comment: If you have a new problem, please post it separately . Stack Overflow is not a good forum for series of questions in the same post.  Each problem should have its own post.